# Как удалить элемент из json?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Я пытался создать event по которому, если человек выходит с сервера, то он удалялся бы из массива

**Код:**

```
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
    users = json.load(f)
    
  users.remove(member.id)
  
  with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(users, f)
```

**Ошибка:**

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

Comment: Что непонятно из текста ошибки?

Comment: @denisnumb все понятно, было непонятно, как удалить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У словарей нет метода `remove()`.

Удаление элемента из словаря производится при помощи оператора `del`:

```
del users[member.id]
```